# Is there something faster than StringBuilder for "parameterized" string building?

Tags: .net, string, performance, t4, stringbuilder

I have a custom little "view" engine made in T4. Basically, what it does is take "static" HTML files with special directives and spits out something like:

```
StringBuilder output... 
output.Append("<html> my code blah");
if(MyParameter!=null){
  output.Append(MyParameter.ToString);
}
output.append("more code");
return output.ToString();
```

Of course, there is more to it than that, but that's the gist. It takes a HTML file and generates a plain-old-C#-class.

I really like it this way because I can have statically-typed views. Unfortunately, this appears to be a bit slow. My problem in particular is that I have a `index` view that multiple contains `blog entry` views, So basically the same basic string ends up getting built, just with a few different pieces of text here and there based on the parameters provided.

Anyway, I'm wondering if there is any way to speed up this process at all. Is there really anything faster than StringBuilder for this?

Also, don't worry about "unclean" code. Because I use T4 to generate these view classes, I can have some pretty hack-ish code and it doesn't matter a whole lot because I'm only writing it once basically.

Comment: That's rather vague, isn't it?  At least collect some evidence that it is actually the builder that's slow.  What do the .NET GC perf counters tell you?  What does a profiler tell you?  Nothing faster than a StringBuilder, using its Capacity property doesn't make much difference on .NET 4.  Something else you didn't mention.

Comment: As far as I know, `StringBuilder` is the recommended way to build strings efficiently. Maybe you could use a stream to send your text straight to its destination rather than building it as a string? Perhaps its T4 that is being slow.

Answer (score 2):

For StringBuilder

- Reuse the StringBuilder object instead of creating an new one every time
- Set the capacity of the StringBuilder to the maximum size of the final string.

Alternatives

- Create a list of all posibble strings and just select from them based on the parameter values (if there are not too many permutations possible)

Also

- Benchmark your code as it is not likely that building strings is holding you back. I can build 300 thousand string/second on a single core.

Comment: +1 for reusing the StringBuilder object. I profiled it in my custom JSON parser and `new StringBuilder` happened to occur on the "hot path". After I rearranged it to a global instance of StringBuilder and `sb.Clear()`, my parser became 3x faster.

Answer (score 0):

Please, specify capacity for created StringBuilder. This will avoid multiple memory allocations. Example:

```
var a = new StringBuilder(3000);
```

where, 3000 is estimated size of final string